# Error 500 laravel after upload files of server

Tags: laravel

I finished a project with laravel 5.2 cms master and I received an error at 500. What could it be?

```
    Error 500

Houston, We Have A Problem.
Internal Server Error

What does this mean?

Something went wrong on our servers while we were processing your request. An error has occurred and this resource cannot be displayed. This occurrence has been logged, and a highly trained team of monkeys has been dispatched to deal with your problem. We're really sorry about this, and will work hard to get this resolved as soon as possible.

This error can be identified by cc577d3d-22a6-4683-b154-38b01d62fd9e. You might want to take a note of this code.

Perhaps you would like to go to our home page?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

/*
 * This file is part of Bootstrap CMS.
 *
 * (c) Graham Campbell <graham@alt-three.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

// send users to the home page
$router->get('/', ['as' => 'base', function () {
    Session::flash('', ''); // work around laravel bug if there is no session yet
    Session::reflash();

    return Redirect::to('pages/home');
}]);

// send users to the posts page
if (Config::get('cms.blogging')) {
    $router->get('blog', ['as' => 'blog', function () {
        Session::flash('', ''); // work around laravel bug if there is no session yet
        Session::reflash();

        return Redirect::route('blog.posts.index');
    }]);
}

// page routes
$router->resource('pages', 'PageController');

// blog routes
if (Config::get('cms.blogging')) {
    $router->resource('blog/posts', 'PostController');
    $router->resource('blog/posts.comments', 'CommentController');
}

// event routes
if (Config::get('cms.events')) {
    $router->resource('events', 'EventController');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be on accessing the files and requiring permissions.

Try running this:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R laravel_blog

chmod -R o+w laravel_blog/storage
```